# Reading a file twice is extremely fast on the second read

Tags: java, caching, inputstream, file-read

I'm currently writing a small program to frequently test my internet speed.
To test the computational overhead I changed the read source to a file on my disk. Here I noticed that the bytewise reading limits the speed at about 31 MB/s so I changed it to reading 512 KB blocks.

Now I have a really strange behavior: After reading a 1GB file for the first time every following read operation is finished in less than one second. But there is no way that my normal HDD reads at over 1 GB/s and I also can't imaging that the whole file is cached in the RAM.

Here's my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");

        try {
            System.out.println("Starting test...");

            InputStream in = (new FileInputStream(new File("path/to/testfile")));

            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long initTime = startTime + 8 * 1000; // start measuring after 8 seconds
            long stopTime = initTime + 15 * 1000; // stop after 15 seconds testing

            boolean initiated = false;
            boolean stopped = false;

            long bytesAfterInit = 0;

            long bytes = 0;

            byte[] b = new byte[524288];

            int bytesRead = 0;

            while((bytesRead = in.read(b)) > 0) {
                bytes += bytesRead;

                if(!initiated && System.currentTimeMillis() > initTime) {
                    initiated = true;
                    System.out.println("initiated");
                    bytesAfterInit = bytes;
                }

                if(System.currentTimeMillis() > stopTime) {
                    stopped = true;
                    System.out.println("stopped");
                    break;
                }
            }

            long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            in.close();

            long duration = 0;
            long testBytes = 0;

            if(initiated && stopped) { //if initiated and stopped calculate for the test time
                duration = endTime - initTime;
                testBytes = bytes - bytesAfterInit;
            } else { //otherwise calculate the whole process
                duration = endTime - startTime;
                testBytes = bytes;
            }

            if(duration == 0) //prevent dividing by zero
                duration = 1;

            String result = sdf.format(new Date()) + "\t" + (testBytes / 1024 / 1024) / (duration / 1000d) + " MB/s";

            System.out.println(duration + " ms");
            System.out.println(testBytes + " bytes");
            System.out.println(result);


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Output:

```
Starting test...
302 ms
1010827264 bytes
09.02.2015 10:20    3192.0529801324506 MB/s
```

I don't have that behavior if I change the source of the file to some file in the internet or a way bigger file on my SSD.

How is it possible that all the bytes are read in such a short period?

Comment: You're seeing the effect of cache priming. After you read the file the first time, most of it is still cached in FS memory. Not a valid benchmark.

Comment: *"...and I also can't imaging that the whole file is cached in the RAM."* Why not?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I don't know. Because it's a whole GB :D But apparently it is. Where does the caching happen? Is Windows doing that?

Comment: Disks include caches on the disk itself, that are much faster than accessing via normal means. They cache frequently or recently accessed data. I'll dig out links in a bit or else someone might provide a more detailed answer before then.

Comment: Yes. Your HDD probably has a built-in cache as well, but it'll be tiny by comparison (64MB sort of thing).

Comment: There are layers of caching. At the hardware level, there is the disk cache. Then there are caches(write-through or write-back) on different layers of the filesystem. It depends on the filesystem.

Comment: @MikeCurry Yeah I was going to say that. The disk caches are way smaller than 1gb. Didn't know that the OS is also caching so much